# Connecting to Istio ingress gateway gives a 404 error

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gateway, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I installed `istio v1.1.1` using the available helm chart.

I have

```
$ kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                                                                                                                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.31.251.20   35.189.53.230   80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15029:31920/TCP,15030:32305/TCP,15031:31084/TCP,15032:31163/TCP,15443:32714/TCP,15020:30964/TCP   3h
```

Then, I created a gateway and virtual service as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: myservice-gateway
  namespace: stg
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "stg.myservice.com"
    port:
      number: 80
      protocol: http
      name: http-myservice-port


---      

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: stg
spec:
  hosts:
    - "stg.myservice.com"
  gateways:
  - myservice-gateway         
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8888
        host: myservice-service.stg.svc.cluster.local
```

I have made sure that the service is running correctly and when I port forward the pod, I can access it using localhost.

I can confirm that `stg.myservice.com` resolves to `35.189.53.230`. 
I get this error

```
$ curl -i stg.myservice.com
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
location: http://stg.myservice.com/
date: Sun, 07 Apr 2019 05:54:59 GMT
server: istio-envoy
content-length: 0
```

What am I missing?

I see no errors in the `ingress-gateway` pod

PS: I have `gateways.istio-ingressgateway.sds.enabled=true`

Comment: So you have a service called `myservice-service` in the namespace `stg`, running on port 8888, and it returns 200 on `/`?

Comment: yes, I can access `http://myservice-service:8888` from another pod in the same cluster

Comment: That's weird. And you say you don't see these requests (that end up with 404) with `kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-xxxxxx-xxxx -n istio-system`? So it never goes through the gateway? Have you tried without SDS?

Comment: Can you paste your `kubectl describe virtualservice` output in the question too?

Answer (score 4):

In your virtualservice config you'll want to add a namespace to the gateway

```
stg/myservice-gateway
```

instead of

```
myservice-gateway
```

so something like this

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: stg
spec:
  hosts:
    - "stg.myservice.com"
  gateways:
  - stg/myservice-gateway         
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8888
        host: myservice-service.stg.svc.cluster.local
```